# How to improve flat, large areas over supports

Tags: print-quality, ultimaker-cura, pla, support-structures, dremel-3d45

I have a similar issue like [this](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/519/how-to-improve-face-that-are-printed-on-support) one. I'm using Cura 5.3.1, a Dremel 3D45 and PLA+ by eSun. The printings are almost perfect and repeatable. The only issue is about flat and large areas over supports.

Like the user of the linked question, I have no problem to remove the supports and they don't leave anything bad on the upper layer. Furthermore I enabled the bridge feature, and even more longer gaps (than the support density) print very nice.

Here a picture:

[image]

As you can see, the small trenches are clean, while the large box in the middle is awful.
The supports have a density of 8 mm with the zig-zag pattern. As said before, even without support I can print very good gaps longer than 30 mm.

To have an idea of the dimensions, the hole has a diameter of 15 mm, and the larger rectangle is 60x45 mm.

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned, there are zigzag patterned supports here, but your area is wide and flat, which can sometimes cause printing errors. You can get better results if you try to print your settings by trying one of the grid pattern or rectilinear pattern options.

They have more points of contact than a zigzag pad and leave less roughness in the area under the printed part.